# Is it possible to make IntelliJ perform "smart" soft wrapping?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Is it possible to make IntelliJ IDEA's soft-wrap behavior smarter? Here's some Java code (from PayPal's ghastly API) and the current soft wrapping behavior:

[image: Current soft wrapping behavior]

Here's the soft wrapping behavior I want to see:

[image: Desired soft wrapping behavior]

Note that I do **NOT** want to reformat the actual text in the file; I only want the *display* of this code to be smart. I use wildly different width monitors and windows from day to day; the code should "look right" on all of them. That doesn't mean "force everything to VT-100 standard 80 cols", as seems to be habitual among non-IDE users.

Comment: Putting this as a comment because I am *almost*, but not entirely, sure: no, Intellij will either provide alignment (i.e., actual reformatting) or leave the code as is. There is a wrapping option, but it's not intelligent in the way you have shown above.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + L can display the code smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. I believe that language plugins can customize soft wrap locations so that code is wrapped at meaningful locations, but wrapped lines cannot be aligned or indented in any way.

Comment: Bummer. With some digging, I found this Feature request and added a vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6076 However, I can't seem to comment on it to link back to this SO question.

Comment: FWIW, I would merrily accept a significant drop in rendering performance to have this feature.